# Deadlock not created when call performBlockAndWait on Main MOC from Main Thread

Tags: ios, core-data

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

```
    if let appDelegateObj = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate{
        print("Before \(Thread.current)")

        appDelegateObj.persistentContainer.viewContext.performAndWait {
            print("I am here \(Thread.current)")
        }

        print("After")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`performAndWait` check what thread it is on first.  If it called on the expected thread (in this case the main thread) it just executes the block.